# Get number of sides of a shape created with LineRenderer in Unity

Tags: unity, 2d, collider

In my game I'm using `LineRenderer` to draw a line at every mouse click.

[image]

As you can see, everytime the lines collides with itself it creates a new shape.

I'm able to detected position using an `EdgeCollider` that I update everytime I add a position to the `LineRenderer`.

This is my code:

```
    private LineRenderer lineRenderer;
private Vector3 target;
private int currentIndex;
private bool hasTarget;
private EdgeCollider2D edgeCollider2D;
private List<Vector2> edgeColliderPoints;

void Start ()
{
    lineRenderer = gameObject.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    edgeCollider2D = gameObject.GetComponent<EdgeCollider2D>();
    currentIndex = 0;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{
    var position = lineRenderer.GetPosition(currentIndex);
    if (hasTarget && target != position)
    {
        var currentPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(position, target, targetSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(currentIndex, currentPosition);

        CheckDetection(currentPosition);
    }
    else
    {
        hasTarget = false;
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && !hasTarget)
    {
        target = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        target.z = 0;
        hasTarget = true;
        currentIndex++;
        lineRenderer.positionCount++;
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(currentIndex,position);
        edgeColliderPoints.Add(transform.InverseTransformPoint(position));
        edgeCollider2D.points = edgeColliderPoints.ToArray();
    }
}

private void CheckDetection(Vector3 currentPosition)
{
    lineRenderer = gameObject.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

    var hit = Physics2D.Linecast(currentPosition, target);

    if (hit.collider != null)
    {
        print("Hit " + hit.collider.name + " at point " + hit.point);
    }
}
```

What I want to do is get the number of sides of every shape that is created after a collision.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Could you provide more explanatory code? People wouldn't know what target is, what are you passing as currentPosition parameter (I'm assuming lineRenderer.GetPosition(index)), and other necessary information. So we could help.

Comment: Added my Update function, basically I get the mouse click and then move my line in that direction.